# How can I conditionally bind a style based on the result of a Predicate on the source object?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I've got a WPF datagrid, and I'm populating it with data from a DataView. I want to conditionally apply a style to each cell of the DataGrid based on the result of a `Predicate` function applied to the source object.

I still don't 'get' WPF databinding, so I'm at a loss as to how do go about this, or where to start. Can anyone give pointers or solutions to how I might do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard (as in "XAML only") way to do such binding. Binding itself allows to specify 1:1 relation between a visual element and a property value (instance or static) on the source. Attributes are not expressed through properties automatically, so you can't bind to them.

However, you could write custom converter that takes the source and checks the type for the existence of the attribute and returns the style name you care about. If you want to make it fancy, the attribute can have the actual style name, although this would mean that your business model would be semi-strongly tied to the presentation, as now it will have a specific knowledge about the view logic.

You can see an example of a custom converter in the Data Binding Overview on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_conversion). In your specific case, you would have to create the binding to the source object itself (not specifying Path) so that younget the actual instance as the value in the Convert method. This would allowyou then to get the Type and check for the attribute, and then create a Style object to return for the binding.

**Update**: If you want to style a specific cell, you need to turn off the AutoGenerateColumns and specify DataGridTempletaColumn for the particular cell. Then you specify your own data template, that is databound to the object and use style selector.

Comment: I've had a play around with `StyleSelector`, but I can't figure out a way of getting the `DataGrid.ItemContainerStyleSelector` to apply to individual cells rather than rows...

Answer (score 0):

You can select a data template for the cell based on an arbitrary property in the view model using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `CellTemplateSelector`.

in the resources:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeCellStyle" DataType="{x:Type local:MyItemViewModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Whatever}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OtherCellStyle" DataType="{x:Type local:MyItemViewModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Whatever}" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

in the DataGrid:

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
                <local:MyItemDataTemplateSelector TypeProperty="Type"
                    DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource SomeCellStyle}"
                    SomeTemplate="{StaticResource SomeCellStyle}"
                    OtherTemplate="{StaticResource OtherCellStyle}" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

code:

```
public class MyItemViewModel
{
    public MyEnum Type { get; set; }
}

public class MyItemDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SomeTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate OtherTemplate { get; set; }
    public string TypeProperty { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            var type = item.GetType();
            var property = type.GetProperty(TypeProperty);
            if (property != null)
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(item, null);
                if (value != null)
                {
                    switch ((MyEnum) value)
                    {
                        case MyEnum.SomeValue:  return SomeTemplate;
                        case MyEnum.OtherValue: return OtherTemplate;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return DefaultTemplate;
    }
}
```